# Create pop up 'toaster' effect message

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to replicate the Gmail Notifier popup.
It both fades in (Opacity) and raises from the start bar.

I've managed to do the fade in\out using a timer and opacity but how do I:

A) make the form appear to 'pop up'? (I think its height grows via a timer from 0 to it's max?

B) Locate it's start point exactly above the task bar as pictured on all screen resolutions\Windows flavours?

[image: Google Notifier]

Comment: I've got to remember avoiding to help you.  Noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

Create "Toast" Popup Notification Windows
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=351757

Works great, includes VB and C# versions too.